# is this multi-variable function 1-1?

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

This question arises from the very first page of Rick Miranda's book "Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces". Specifically, it states that the function $\phi(x,y)=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\frac{y}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ (from any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$-it doesn't really matter-to $\mathbb{C}$) is 1-1. Despite looking easy at first, I can't think of a way to prove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $z=x+iy$, then your mapping is $(x,y) \mapsto z \mapsto \dfrac{z}{1+|z|}$.

Let $\dfrac{z}{1+|z|}=\dfrac{w}{1+|w|}$. Then taking magnitudes of each side you get: $\dfrac{|z|}{1+|z|}=\dfrac{|w|}{1+|w|}$.

The derivative of $\dfrac{r}{1+r}$ is  $\dfrac{1}{(1+r)^2}$ which is clearly positive, so since $\dfrac{r}{1+r}$ is strictly increasing for all $r \geq 0$. It is 1-to-1.

This gives $|z|=|w|$ and thus $\dfrac{z}{1+|z|}=\dfrac{w}{1+|w|}=\dfrac{w}{1+|z|}$ and so $z=w$.

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\phi(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\frac r{1+r}(\cos\theta,\sin\theta),$$all you kneed is to know is that the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,+\infty)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\r&\mapsto&\displaystyle\frac r{1+r}\end{array}$$is injective.

Comment: Actually the "all you need to know" part is the easiest part, but let's see if I got this right. You set $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$ (polar coordinate transformation, which is unique) and the function becomes $\phi(rcos\theta,rsin\theta)=\frac{rcos\theta}{1+r}+i\frac{rsin\theta}{1+r}$ which is $\frac{r}{1+r}e^{i\theta}$. Still though, if $\frac{r_1}{1+r_1}e^{i\theta_1}=\frac{r_2}{1+r_2}e^{i\theta_2}$ how it will lead to $r_1=r_2$, $\theta_1=2k\pi+\theta_2$? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user128787 $\theta_1=2k\pi+\theta_2\Longrightarrow r(\cos\theta_1,\sin\theta_1)=r(\cos\theta_2,\sin\theta_2)$.

Comment: yes but I don't have the $\theta_1=2k\pi+\theta_2$. If I have $\frac{r_1}{1+r_1}e^{i\theta_1}=\frac{r_2}{1+r_2}e^{i\theta_2}$ then it yields $\frac{r_1}{1+r_1}sin\theta_1=\frac{r_2}{1+r_2}sin\theta_2$ and $\frac{r_1}{1+r_1}cos\theta_1=\frac{r_2}{1+r_2}cos\theta_2$. Is there a way to take $\theta_1=2k\pi+\theta_2$?

Comment: @user128787 $\frac{r_1}{1+r_1}e^{i\theta_1}=\frac{r_2}{1+r_2}e^{i\theta_2}\Longrightarrow\left|\frac{r_1}{1+r_1}e^{i\theta_1}\right|=\left|\frac{r_2}{1+r_2}e^{i\theta_2}\right|\Longleftrightarrow\frac{r_1}{1+r_1}=\frac{r_2}{1+r_2}\Longleftrightarrow r_1=r_2.$